# Google Maps error "Couln't get connection factory client" for android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to develop android app which has two screens, and in the second I want google map to be shown...I read everything about this problem everywhere I could find and I did all steps to get API key, I edited Manifest xml file, the second screen xml file (where i want google maps)...provided API key, I set it in previously mentioned xml files, allowed using of internet etc... and still..the problem persists. If anynone has any idea what could be a problem, please answer !

Here's some code i wrote:
Manifest(xml) file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidgui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
   <activity android:name=".Mapa"
android:label="@string/screen2Title">
  <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="API_KEY"/>
   </activity>


</application>
```

xml file of screen i want google maps to be displayed at:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:apiKey="API_KEY"
android:clickable="true"
/>
```

Java file of the screen :

```
   package com.example.androidgui;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

    public class Mapa extends MapActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen);
MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use deprecated Google Maps Android API v1 and mix it with Google Maps Android API v2 key.

The easiest way to start with v2 is removing all the code you have related to maps and following instructions here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: I did everyithing you said, and what is explained by Google..and i get blank background in app...thanks for reply btw !